# What qualifies a "Perfect Run" in asphalt 8?

Tags: asphalt-8

On some single player courses to get a star you need to get a number of perfect runs? What makes a perfect run? What i know so far

- Cannot hit a wall
- Need to be going at near full speed (e.g. cannot turn accelerator off)

Is there anything else

- Does hitting other cars stop the perfect run
- What about other objects that give nitro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the asphalt 8 wiki [(Perfect Run)](http://asphalt.wikia.com/wiki/Perfect_Run) you can perform a perfect run by

1. Not hitting any walls
2. Not wrecking or being knocked down

for 20 seconds or more in any race. However you must drive as smoothly as you can, so your partly right with your going near top speed point however you do have to slow down for corners obviously so you can let off the accelerator for this purpose.

To answer your second set of points, knocking other racers or cars down DOES NOT effect your perfect run neither does destroying obstacles.

The wiki also states that hitting the edge of ramps or falling off the map does not effect your perfect run either.

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's stated that "no hitting the wall," maybe hitting another car is the same as hitting the wall, so yes hitting a car can stop the perfect run and that will be counted as a knockdown.